# Codeigniter URI error with permitted characters

Tags: php, codeigniter

The URI I meant with is namely:

`/ar/users/verify/5454kj/said%40kdfdsf.dff`

Where the last URI segment is an email address encoded using the PHP function `urlencode`. The `application/config/config.php` `permitted_uri_chars` has the follwoing value:

`$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';` so `%` and `.` are permitted. So what is the problem? does it a bug in CodeIgniter 2.2.0? Does it related with IIS?

Comment: How are you using this URI and what's the error you're getting?

Comment: I use it in verification code email link. The error is: `The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.`

Comment: `http://mywebsite.com/ar/users/verify/aZeAbh6Of12zM8rjFOSsW084M433tS5G1999/said%40email.com` I receive this in verify action which is defined as `public function verify($code = null, $email = null){}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%40` is causing an issue and is disallowed since it is interpreted as `@`.  This question explains this issue as well: [Codeigniter Redirect -- The URI you submitted has disallowed characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297433/codeigniter-redirect-the-uri-you-submitted-has-disallowed-characters)

You are better off passing the email as a query string value `http://mywebsite.com/ar/users/verify/aZeAbh6Of12zM8rjFOSsW084M433tS5G1999?email=said@email.com` which will work properly (assuming that you have query strings enabled).

Another option is to edit your `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` to allow for `@`.